# While concatenating two columns an output mismatch occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query:

```
 SELECT v.PassNo, VName, e.eName, d.dtName, v.EntryTime
   FROM Visitorlogo_tbl v
        LEFT JOIN EmployeeMaster_tbl e ON v.empid=e.eId
             JOIN DepartmentMaster_tbl d ON v.Deptid=d.dtId
  WHERE v.EntryTime >= '2014-06-29'
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
PassNo    VName    eName    dtName    EntryTime
100       jaseem   null     admin     2014-06-29 23:17:47.257
101       deepu    sabu     sales     2014-06-29 24:17:47.257
103       rabeeh   null     IT        2014-06-30 23:17:47.257
```

Because I want to concatenate **`ename`** and **`dtname`**, I wrote the query like this:

```
 SELECT v.PassNo AS 'Badge Id', VName AS VisitorName,
        e.eName + ' ('+ d.dtName+')' AS 'Name(Department)', v.EntryTime
   FROM Visitorlogo_tbl v
             JOIN DepartmentMaster_tbl d ON v.Deptid = d.dtId
        LEFT JOIN EmployeeMaster_tbl e ON v.empid = e.eId
  WHERE v.EntryTime >= '2014-06-29'
```

However, this leads to a mismatch in the output:

```
Badge Id  VisitorName    Name(Department)   EntryTime
100       jaseem         null               2014-06-29 23:17:47.257
101       deepu          sabu               2014-06-29 24:17:47.257
103       rabeeh         null               2014-06-30 23:17:47.257
```

Why am I seeing `NULL` instead of the department name for badge id's `100` and `103`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating strings, where one of your strings are `NULL` will always yield `NULL`.
For example: `SELECT NULL + 'Moo'` will result in `NULL` - always.
`ISNULL()` accepts 2 arguments and will return the second when the first resolves to `NULL` - [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Do you mean to do this?

```
SELECT   [Badge Id]         = v.PassNo
        ,VisitorName        = VName
        ,[Name(Department)] = ISNULL(e.eName, '') + ISNULL(' (' + d.dtName + ')', '')
        ,v.EntryTime 
FROM Visitorlogo_tbl        V
JOIN DepartmentMaster_tbl   D ON v.Deptid=d.dtId
LEFT 
JOIN EmployeeMaster_tbl     E ON v.empid=e.eId
WHERE v.EntryTime >= '2014-06-29'
```

Comment: Concatenating strings, where one of your strings are NULL will always yield NULL. For example: SELECT NULL + 'Moo' will result in NULL - always.

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate null with anything, it will return null. So you need to check for null to get the proper result. You can use the following query instead

```
select v.PassNo as 'Badge Id',VName as VisitorName,ISNULL(e.eName,'') + ISNULL(' ('+ d.dtName+')','') as 'Name(Department)',v.EntryTime from Visitorlogo_tbl v
  join DepartmentMaster_tbl d on v.Deptid=d.dtId
left join EmployeeMaster_tbl e on v.empid=e.eId
where v.EntryTime >='2014-06-29'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  v.PassNo as 'Badge Id',
        VName as VisitorName,
        ISNULL(e.eName,'') + ISNULL(' ('+ d.dtName+')','') as 'Name(Department)',
        v.EntryTime 
FROM    Visitorlogo_tbl v
JOIN     DepartmentMaster_tbl d on v.Deptid=d.dtId
LEFT JOIN EmployeeMaster_tbl e on v.empid=e.eId
WHERE   v.EntryTime >='2014-06-29'
```